# Heroku application error logs, cannot run heroku open

Tags: python, django, heroku, application-error

When I run Heroku open I get an error

> Application error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
> served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
> You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
>
> ```
> heroku logs --tail
> ```

What could possibly be the problem? Can a problem with DJANGO_SECRET_KEY cause such problem ?

this is my logs

```
2021-06-11T05:06:11.906892+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user a
2021-06-11T05:06:11.906892+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user a
2021-06-11T05:06:12.046032+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user a
2021-06-11T05:06:12.046032+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user a
2021-06-11T06:24:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user
2021-06-11T06:25:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/67a0bf8e-56f4-41bd-b9de-b02c9ca20f13/activity/builds/b4469f36-8883-468b-95a2-aadaa03ff662
2021-06-11T06:36:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user a
2021-06-11T06:36:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/67a0bf8e-56f4-41bd-b9de-b02c9ca20f13/activity/builds/254007fa-69b7-45d7-9490-5bd0643ec3cf
2021-06-11T06:37:40.559478+00:00 app[api]: Set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC config vars by user a
2021-06-11T06:37:40.559478+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user a
2021-06-11T06:38:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user a
2021-06-11T06:38:41.947391+00:00 app[api]: Running release v4 commands by user a
2021-06-11T06:38:41.947391+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-fitted-13790) by user a
2021-06-11T06:38:41.960986+00:00 app[api]: @ref:postgresql-fitted-13790 completed provisioning, setting DATABASE_URL. by user a
2021-06-11T06:38:41.960986+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user a
2021-06-11T06:38:42.248836+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user a
2021-06-11T06:38:42.248836+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 631aaa14 by user a
2021-06-11T06:38:42.263855+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user a
2021-06-11T06:38:47.377590+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn taskmate.wsgi`
2021-06-11T06:38:49.701398+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-06-11T06:38:49.759979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-11T06:38:49.786811+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-11T06:38:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-06-11T06:38:54.704761+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn taskmate.wsgi`
2021-06-11T06:38:56.938703+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-06-11T06:38:57.009000+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-11T06:39:21.946361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=taskmatealex.herokuapp.com request_id=03769758-3201-4ace-84d7-eff640f19e64 fwd="103.70.154.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-11T06:39:22.615862+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=taskmatealex.herokuapp.com request_id=a3bb074c-e730-47e5-a8d8-3a56a654d536 fwd="103.70.154.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-11T06:44:11.320345+00:00 app[api]: Set DJANGO_SECRET_KEY config vars by user a
2021-06-11T06:44:11.320345+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user a
2021-06-11T06:44:11.681506+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-11T06:44:16.640737+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn taskmate.wsgi`
2021-06-11T06:44:20.185781+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-06-11T06:44:20.627488+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-11T06:44:45.899230+00:00 app[api]: Set DJANGO_DEBUG config vars by user a
2021-06-11T06:44:45.899230+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user a
2021-06-11T06:44:46.186652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-11T06:44:51.580724+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn taskmate.wsgi`
2021-06-11T06:44:53.930104+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-06-11T06:44:53.996520+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-11T06:45:49.132605+00:00 app[api]: Set DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS config vars by user a
2021-06-11T06:45:49.132605+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user a
2021-06-11T06:45:50.149885+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-11T06:45:55.131936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn taskmate.wsgi`
2021-06-11T06:45:57.900136+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-06-11T06:45:57.975963+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-11T06:46:16.613566+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=taskmatealex.herokuapp.com request_id=75595574-8bfd-4851-92a7-667346862310 fwd="103.70.154.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-11T06:46:17.030878+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=taskmatealex.herokuapp.com request_id=88926793-6033-41cb-8b5b-5d80d227ec44 fwd="103.70.154.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-11T06:46:48.270024+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=taskmatealex.herokuapp.com request_id=caba852e-9548-4020-a230-d59a94770034 fwd="103.70.154.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-11T06:46:48.896248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=taskmatealex.herokuapp.com request_id=fa079ddf-ba6d-4b0a-8bb7-44171a2e89f0 fwd="103.70.154.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-11T06:52:16.814200+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-11T06:52:22.174366+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn taskmate.wsgi`
2021-06-11T06:52:26.162459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-06-11T06:52:26.256358+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: Execute your django project directly without hiding it behind gunicorn WSGI. Gunicorn doesn't redirect the error logs. Gunicorn is also not compatible with all django projects.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: How are you executing your project locally? You probably aren't using gunicorn to do that.

Comment: In this project example: https://github.com/ericmjl/minimal-flask-example `python app.py` executes the flask app without hiding it behind gunicorn. `web: gunicorn app:app` executes the file `app.py` in which the object `app` is defined and hides that behind WSGI. Note that in the latter case inside `app.py` `if __name__ == "__main__":`returns `False` thus the last line is not executed.

Comment: There should be no problem using gunicorn.. you can add `--log-file blah.txt` to save logs if you want.. then use heroku bash to see the file contents. Anyways, what is in the wsgi.py file? Does the settings file specified in the wsgi exist?.. or do you have your settings setup differently than Django's default method?

Comment: the wsgi.py is `import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'taskmate.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
` I didn't change the settings.py besides what I saw in the tutorial

Comment: actually, never mind, there was a problem in my Procfile. It's working fine now.Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

my Procfile was incorrect
I changed it from

```
web: gunicorn taskmate.wsgi
```

to

```
web: gunicorn taskmate.wsgi:application --log-file - --log-level debug
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
manage.py migrate
```